# How do I run some python code in another process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to start, from Python, some other Python code, preferably a function, but in **another process**.

It is mandatory to run this in another process, because I want to run some concurrency tests, like opening a file that was opened exclusively by the parent process (this has to fail).

Requirements:

- multiplatform: linux, osx, windows
- compatible with Python 2.6-3.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to duplicate fork() in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397/whats-the-best-way-to-duplicate-fork-in-windows)

Comment: @AJ that's about Windows, this is about Python.  I don't see how it could possibly be a duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would seriously take a look at the documentation for [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) library of Python.  From the first sentence of the package's description:

> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the threading module.

It then goes on to say that it side-steps the GIL, which is what it sounds like you're trying to avoid.  See their example of a trivial set up:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print 'hello', name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

That's a function call being done in another process separate from the process you're inside.  Again, all this from the documentation.