# Run a .bat program in the background on Windows

Tags: python, process, background, batch-file, subprocess

I am trying to run a `.bat` file (which acts as a simulator) in a new window, so it must always be running in the background. I think that creating a new process is the only option that I have. Basically, I want my code to do something like this:

```
    def startSim:
        # open .bat file in a new window
        os.system("startsim.bat")
        # continue doing other stuff here
        print("Simulator started")
```

I'm on Windows so I can't do `os.fork`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397/whats-the-best-way-to-duplicate-fork-in-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818774/python-subprocess)

Comment: already read the one on making an os.fork on windows, I need something that I won't have to install a module or program(cygwin) to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `subprocess.Popen` (not tested on Windows, but should work).

```
import subprocess

def startSim():
    child_process = subprocess.Popen("startsim.bat")

    # Do your stuff here.

    # You can terminate the child process after done.
    child_process.terminate()
    # You may want to give it some time to terminate before killing it.
    time.sleep(1)
    if child_process.returncode is None:
        # It has not terminated. Kill it. 
        child_process.kill()
```

Edit: you could also use `os.startfile` (Windows only, not tested too).

```
import os

def startSim():
    os.startfile("startsim.bat")
    # Do your stuff here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want "os.spawn*", which seems to equate to os.fork, but for Windows.
Some searching turned up this example:

```
# File: os-spawn-example-3.py

import os
import string

if os.name in ("nt", "dos"):
    exefile = ".exe"
else:
    exefile = ""

def spawn(program, *args):
    try:
        # check if the os module provides a shortcut
        return os.spawnvp(program, (program,) + args)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    try:
        spawnv = os.spawnv
    except AttributeError:
        # assume it's unix
        pid = os.fork()
        if not pid:
            os.execvp(program, (program,) + args)
        return os.wait()[0]
    else:
        # got spawnv but no spawnp: go look for an executable
        for path in string.split(os.environ["PATH"], os.pathsep):
            file = os.path.join(path, program) + exefile
            try:
                return spawnv(os.P_WAIT, file, (file,) + args)
            except os.error:
                pass
        raise IOError, "cannot find executable"

#
# try it out!

spawn("python", "hello.py")

print "goodbye"
```

Comment: is this python 2.7 only ?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, a background process is called a "service". Check this other question about how to create a Windows service with Python: [Creating a python win32 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263296/creating-a-python-win32-service)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/path/script.bat'], 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Using subprocess.Popen() will run the given .bat path ( or any other executable).

If you do wish to wait for the process to finish just add proc.wait():

```
proc.wait()
```