# Process creation in python Windows with console

Tags: python, process

I have a function in python with arguments.Within the same file I call that function(**call it foo**). Is there any way in python(**for Win7**) that I can create different independent processes from the parent process with each process executing foo with different set of arguments(obviously independent from the parent process as well)? 
**Can a console be also attached to these process?**

PS: I know that if it is a separate script or exe then we can use **Popen.subprocess()** module. But here the problem is of assigning a function(code) to different process(independent from each other as well as of the parent).

This is the function.

```
import subprocess
import os
import string
def add(x,y):
     return x+y
```

This is the input file:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Now if function were written in some separate file(add.py) we can directly use **subprocess.Popen()** to call "add.py" for each set of arguments from the input file. But if the function is written in the same file as the main file then how to assign a new process to each set of arguments from the input file shown? 
I can't use **fork()** because there isn't any for Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397/whats-the-best-way-to-duplicate-fork-in-windows

Comment: @Sam But I am reading a file(a loop) and creating a new Process every time for each set of args.Also they should be independent of parent process and should have a separate console.

Comment: Why dont you just run each function call in a thread? - why the need for a seperate process? - if you want a window for each thread, just as a monitor, consider a simple GUI like tKinter and add a text frame whenever you create a new thread..

Comment: @Henrik threads would be dependent on the parent process. I need that function to be in infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. 
I wouldn't choose this path myself, but it's possible.
This is sometimes referred to as a detached process, or a daemon.

better implementations for deamons exists, but the basic idea can be achieved using this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

print "runMe started"
print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)

def runMeAsChild(args):
    if args is None or len(args) == 0:
        args = []
        args.append("stop")
    cmd = "start cmd /k python " + sys.argv[0]+ " " + " ".join(args)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    runMeAsChild(["test"])
    runMeAsChild(["once", "again"])
```

*if you want the console to automatically close after execution, use `/c` instead of `/k` in the cmd string*