# I'm getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fork' when i run my program on windows. How can i fix this?

Tags: python, fork

I tried calling the `os.fork()` in the `parent()` funtion but yet it gives me the same error.

**this is my code:**

```
import os

def child():
    print('Hello from child', os.getpid())
    os._exit(0) # else goes back to parent loop

def parent():
    while True:
        newpid = os.fork()
        if newpid == 0:
            child()
        else:
            print('Hello from parent', os.getpid(), newpid)
        if input() == 'q': break

parent()
```

Comment: Probably of interest is the SO question [What's the best way to duplicate fork() in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397/whats-the-best-way-to-duplicate-fork-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

`os.fork()`is only available in Unix. See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork).