# Why is this message printed more than once during multiprocessing with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecuter()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

The statement "I should appear only once" should appear only once. I am not able to understand why it appears 3 more times... 
It's clear to me that my code is executing 3 further processes. But in these 3 processes only `funktion0()` is getting called. Why does the statement `"I should appear only once"` get included in these extra 3 processes? Could someone explain?

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
#print(datetime.now().time())

from time import time, sleep
#print(time())
print("I should appear only once")
from concurrent import futures


def funktion0(arg0):
    sleep(arg0)
    print(f"ich habe {arg0} sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: {datetime.now().time()}")

if __name__=="__main__":

    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as obj0:
        obj0.submit(funktion0, 5)
        obj0.submit(funktion0, 10)
        obj0.submit(funktion0, 15)
        obj0.submit(funktion0, 20)
        print("alle Aufgaben gestartet")

    print("alle Aufgaben erledigt")
```

Expected output:

```
I should appear only once
alle Aufgaben gestartet
ich habe 5 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:32:51.926288
ich habe 10 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:32:56.923648
ich habe 15 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:33:01.921168
ich habe 20 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:33:11.929370
alle Aufgaben erledigt
```

Actual output:

```
I should appear only once
alle Aufgaben gestartet
I should appear only once
I should appear only once
I should appear only once
ich habe 5 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:32:51.926288
ich habe 10 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:32:56.923648
ich habe 15 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:33:01.921168
ich habe 20 sek. gewartet, aktuelle Zeit: 18:33:11.929370
alle Aufgaben erledigt
```

Comment: please tag your question as windows, as it's probably is windows-related only.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the classic issue with windows ([RuntimeError on windows trying python multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204782/runtimeerror-on-windows-trying-python-multiprocessing)) only less dramatic.

When you're using multiprocessing on windows, the process isn't forked but duplicated (because `fork` doesn't exist in windows OS) using some tricky mechanism to "emulate" `fork` but not accurately because OS doesn't allow it ([What's the best way to duplicate fork() in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397/whats-the-best-way-to-duplicate-fork-in-windows)).

So the statement is printed as many times as there are processes, unless you protect it with `__name__ == "__main__"`

(you can probably speed up workers startup by moving most `import` statements in that scope too)